# Нежелательное наложение текста

Tags: qt

При редактировании `QTableView` текст накладывается на текст, который был до этого в поле. Как этого избежать? Желательно подробный ответ: я новичок в Qt.

[image: Текст накладывается]

Код

```
QApplication a(argc, argv);

MainWindow w;
w.show();

QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
db.setDatabaseName(QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath()+"/t.db");
db.open();

QSqlTableModel *model = new QSqlTableModel(0, db);
model->setEditStrategy(QSqlTableModel::OnFieldChange);
model->setTable("vaska");
model->select();
/*этот метод просто возвращает QTableView*/
w.getTableView()->setModel(model);
return a.exec();
```

Окно — стандартное, при использовании QtCreator, только ещё добавлено одно `QTableView` и всё.

Comment: Думаю, что это глюк Qt, у меня такое же наблюдается в другой программе на Линуксе

Comment: @zenden2k странная какая-то ошибка. Я попробовал скомпилировать с последней стабильной версией Qt — тот же самый результат. И к тому же, похоже в самом Qt Creator есть та же ошибка — проявляется при редактировании Build Environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На [английской версии StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33439755/2586997) посоветовали добавить пустой стиль к `QTableView`, тогда текст не накладывается:

```
view->setStyleSheet("QTableView::item {}");
```

Если же эта, по-видимому, ошибка возникла не в вашей программе, то можно записать в файл style.qss код: `QTableView::item {}` и подключить его так: `./app -stylesheet=style.qss`